# Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1 Installation - Bootstrap 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework, installation

When running the installation script for **Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1** I am getting the following error:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

This occurs during the `BootStrapCommerceServices` step of the installation. Directly after logging:

```
PUT https://commerceshops.sc9.qa/commerceops/Bootstrap() with 0-byte
```

Below is the error I get in the shops log file, it doesn't mean anything to me and I have not be able to find any relevant information on the error, but perhaps someone recognizes it:

```
ERROR Message=SQL.GetDBVersion.Fail: Environment='GlobalEnvironment'|Message='Could not find stored procedure 'sp_CommerceDBVersionGet'.'|Number='2812'|Procedure=''|Line='1'|CorrelationId=3a39ea7b355848989241178fab405522|StackTace=   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

Based on various blog post regarding errors in the commerce 9 installation I change the connection string SQL server name to `{MACHINE}\\SQLEXPRESS` in the following files:

- \SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot\appsettings.json
- \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
- \CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
- \CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
- \CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
- \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json
- \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json
- \CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.AdventureWorks.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json

In the `Global.json` files I even changed the second occurrence of the database property from `SitecoreCommerce_Global` to `SitecoreCommerce9_Global`.

I have also attempted to add a username and password to both the connection string in `appsettings.json` and the `Global.json` files.

None of these changes have helped. Is there something else that I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had previously installed a different version of **Sitecore Experience Commerce**. Removing the old installation (IIS sites and app pools, directories, databases and solr cores), and re-running the script fixed the issue.