# Sitecore commerce 9.1 Installation failed - 502.5 Failed to start

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-server

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce 9.1 locally, I have followed the [installation guide](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.1/Sitecore_XC-9.1_Installation_Guide_for_On-Prem.pdf) and all went well until I get this exception. I can see there are four websites created in IIS(CommerceAuthoring_Sc911com,CommerceMinions_Sc911com,CommerceOps_Sc911com, CommerceShops_Sc911com)

[image]

I have looked into the Event viewer and found below:

> MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/COMMERCESHOPS_SC911COM' with physical root
>   'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc911com\' created process with
>   commandline
>   'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc911com\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe
>   ' but failed to listen on the given port '46791'

Does anyone seen this error or know how to fix this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

- Sitecore version: 9.1.1
- SIF version: 2.1.0
- Powershell extensions version: 5.0
- SXA: 1.8.1 rev 190319fpr 9.1.1
- Dotnet core: 2.1.505

A snippet of Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1

> CommerceEngineDacPac                        = "C:\Sitecore\install\XC911\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"
>           CommerceOpsServicesPort                     = "5015"
>           CommerceShopsServicesPort                   = "5005"
>           CommerceAuthoringServicesPort               = "5000"
>           CommerceMinionsServicesPort                 = "5010"
>           SitecoreBizFxPort                           = "4200"

I have seen this [post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18500/sitecore-experience-commerce-9-1-installation-bootstrap-500-internal-server-er) but looks like that not exactly what I am facing here.

Comment: Is port 46791 already used on your machine?

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi it's not been used.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a shot in the dark. Perhaps excessive security? Third party antivirus? Ports locked down?

Comment: What version of .net core did you installed?

Comment: But according to the PowerShell script, CommerceShopsServices should be listening to port 5005. Don't know why it's trying to listen to 46791.

Comment: @VladIobagiu 2.1.505 commit b2202231234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred due to a previous error in creating databases (SitecoreCommerce9_Global, SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments). Installation carried forward even though there were no databases and failed with the above error at later stage.

To fix this run command below in the same PowerShell session:

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "msg" | Unregister-Event
```